# LOAD DATA LOCAL statement taking a little while on MySql RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

So i have the following issue, i have a medium sized databased (1.6 gigabytes ). And i am running the following, statement in RDS MySql.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "E:/csms/Query/Tratado_interno/Dataset_Raw.csv"
INTO TABLE Eventtracks_Take.Prod
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
ENCLOSED BY '"'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

It has come to my attention, that such load into were supposed to occur on very high speeds at least that is what people in tutorials show, around 1 second no longer no less. But the ones i am handling take around 3.6 minutes. Any ideas on what could be the probable cause? My EC2 instance is t3.large so i would expect that that is not the cause of the issue. Sometimes i also run into a few specific warnings telling me a specific column of data was truncated even tho i can guarantee i gave it enough character on the schema. Nonetheless, would appreciate any given theory.

Comment: `LOAD DATA INFILE` is fast, because the database reads the file directly from disk. But with `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` the network is the bottleneck. The only way to speed it up is to get a faster Internet connection or run it on a machine in the same datacenter as the server.

Comment: If you're getting the truncation error, make sure that all the fields are actually enclosed by `"`. That might need to be `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY`

Comment: I see, well i will try your thesis

Comment: Just out of curiosity if you had to load a quite biggies dataset into an rds how would you do it?

Comment: This is the the best way to do it. You just have to understand that it takes a while to transfer that much data over the Internet.

Comment: Who said you can load 1.6GB into any database in 1 second? It's true that LOAD DATA will be more efficient than inserting row-by-row using INSERT statements, but no solution guarantees sub-second results without regard to the size of the payload.

Comment: Also one should not use a t3 instance type and be surprised at poor performance. Those "burstable" instance types run out of burst credits very fast, and then they fall back to "baseline" performance which is terrible. If you need sustained performance for bulk operations, then you shouldn't use a t3 instance type. Sorry, in the cloud, you get what you pay for, and sometimes you don't even get that.

Comment: @BillKarwin i just took a glance at few tutorials and well they were very fast. But they were transfering data directly from the disk. Which diminishs a lot of the tiime. After Barmar explained something i should have know to be sincere, that it uses internet for such transfer i understood why  it takes a little longer

Comment: @BillKarwin I see what instance would you recommend for me to use? I think i shall do such load commands continously to be  sincere.

Comment: Practically any instance family other than `t`. I have used `m`, `c`, `r`, and `i`. The `t` family have burstable performance, which means only in short bursts. It's my opinion that the `t` instances are good for testing or development, but not for production.